# Need Guidance on Performance Optimization in CAS 7.0.2

Tags: cas

I'm migrating from CAS 6.6.14 version to 7.0.2 with Microsoft Entra as Delegated authentication.
The CAS Server is deployed on Kubernetes with two instances running, each configured with 2 cores and 6 GB of RAM.

During load testing, irrespective of the user load (10, 20, 50, or 100 users per second) CAS perfromance degrades significantly.
The CPU utilization peaks at 100%, and the RAM gradually reaches full capacity, ultimately leading to the restart of each pod due to Out of Memory issues.

With the same configuration on CAS 6.6.14 there are no problem with the CPU and RAM.

I use Redis ticket registy as a storage for tickets with following configuration:

```
cas.ticket.registry.redis.host=redis-master
cas.ticket.registry.redis.database=0
cas.ticket.registry.redis.port=6379
cas.ticket.registry.redis.password=<redacted>
cas.ticket.registry.redis.timeout=2000
cas.ticket.registry.redis.use-ssl=false
cas.ticket.registry.redis.enabled=true
cas.ticket.registry.redis.pool.enabled=false
cas.ticket.registry.redis.enable-redis-search=false
cas.ticket.registry.redis.username=
```

Any suggestions how to handle this. I'm expecting a user load of about 100-150 users per second.

I have tried increasing the tomcat configuration:

```
server.tomcat.accept-count=500
server.tomcat.max-connections=8192
server.tomcat.max-keep-alive-requests=100
```